# Index value for corresponding maximum value of difference between 2 Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a csv file consisting list of countries and Corresponding summer and winter Gold medals that each country (index in dataframe) has won. Something like this -

```
               Gold     Gold.1
Algeria           5          0
Armenia           8          1
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
def Max_Diff():
    Gold_Diff = []
    Diff = 0
    for row in df.iterrows():
        Diff = df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']
    Gold_Diff.append(Diff)
    return max(Gold_Diff)`enter code here`

Max_Diff()
```

And so on. 'Gold' is gold medals won in summer and 'Gold.1' is gold medals won in winter.

I need to find the country that has maximum difference between Gold(summer) and Gold(winter) count. My code was to, first iterate over all the rows in dataframe and append a list consisting of the countries and corresponding difference. And then apply the max function on the list to get the value of the country with maximum difference

But the above code renders the entire list as is and not one value.

Also, before this approach, I tried to convert this list into a Series using pd.Series(Gold_Diff). but the conversion is not happening properly, the output is something like this -

Algeria         5
Armeni.....
dtype: object

The idea behind converting to series was to use the idxmax function on the series post conversion and get the index value (country name) of maximum difference value in the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the difference between the columns using

```
df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']
```

If you are interested in absolute difference, use

```
abs(df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1'])
```

The above code returns a pandas series. You can get the name of the country with the highest difference using idxmax()

```
(abs(df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1'])).idxmax()
```

Comment: Thats good, may be you can accept the answer if the question is completely resolved

Comment: @Vaishali can you please add more explanation? It will help the OP and and future visitors significantly more.

Comment: @ Kyle, added some explanation :)